# reading same input with bufio and scanf has different results

Tags: go, input, printing

I was trying to write a simple program that reads some answers from the terminal from the user to some questions.For instance the queries are:

```
5+5
1+2
8+3
```

and the user should give the answer.My problem it that when I user **bufio.ReadString** and the compare the input with the real answer it doesn't work properly,how ever when I use scanf everything is fine.here is my code:

```
//scanner := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    var correctAnswers int8 = 0

    for _, pro := range problems {
        fmt.Println(pro.question)
        //answer,_ := scanner.ReadString('\n')
        var idk string
        fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &idk)
        //print(answer)
        println(pro.answer)
        if idk == pro.answer {
            fmt.Println("Correct :)")
            correctAnswers++
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Sorry!")
        }

    }
    fmt.Printf("You answered %d out of %d problems correctly \n", correctAnswers, len(problems))
```

as you can see I commented out bufio. The intersting thing is that when I print the answer that the user gave me it bufio.ReadString correctly got the input from terminal but in the if clause it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bufio.Reader.ReadString`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString):

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and **including the delimiter**.

The value returned from `ReadString` includes the `\n` on the end.

Comment: Trim the whitespace from the string.